# Virtual disk size information seems incorrect, but unable to do any partitioning operations

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, vmware

I have a `.vmdk` file which I have to extract data from. I added the `.vmdk` file as a secondary hard drive(`/dev/sdb`) for a virtual machine, and tried to mount it but it was unsuccessful.

```
# mount /dev/sdb ./target

mount: /home/suhdonghwi/Documents/target: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I ran `fdisk` and output was:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

GPT PMBR size mismatch (524287999 != 260503551) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sdb: 124.22 GiB, 133377818624 bytes, 260503552 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 260503551 260503551 124.2G ee GPT
```

Seeing `GPT PMBR size mismatch (524287999 != 260503551)`, I ran `gdisk` verification:

```
# gdisk /dev/sdb

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR
```

```
Command (? for help): v

Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
(Disk size is 260503552 sectors, needs to be 524288000 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 524287966, but backup header is at
524287999 and disk size is 260503552 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem

Problem: partition 3 is too big for the disk.

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Identified 6 problems!
```

`gdisk` suggested me to go expert mode and type `e` for repairing the problems. But it was unsuccessful again:

```
Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): e
Relocating backup data structures to the end of the disk

Expert command (? for help): w

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
263782433 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Problem: partition 3 is too big for the disk.
Aborting write operation!
Aborting write of new partition table.
```

Saying that I have to resize partition 3 in another utility. So I tried using `parted` to do so, but the following errors came out:

```
(parted) p                                                                
Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdb
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? I                                                    
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? O                                                              
Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 133GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I think it has something to do with the incorrect size information. I have `-flat.vmdk` and `.vmdk` files. I also tried recreating `.vmdk` descriptor file, but with no luck. I ran out of solutions, what should I do?

Comment: Use `testdisk` and scan for known filesystems ("lost partitions"). Does it find anything that looks like the filesystem you're looking for?

Comment: Does this post apply here: [Mounting windows 10 GPT Partition centos 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281688/mounting-windows-10-gpt-partition-centos-6)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, it finds the filesystem I'm looking for(third partition).

Comment: @harrymc My filesystem is not ntfs, so it seems unrelated I think?

Comment: Just in case, backup the original `.vmdk` and related files. Then let `testdisk` recover the lost partition (chapter 9 [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf)). Run `partprobe` if needed; check `lsblk`. Finally mount.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I ran `testdisk` recovery and partition table errors were gone! But the problem is that `fdisk` says total size of `Linux filesystem` is only 1GB. And I still can't mount with the same error (wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock...).

Comment: This means *probably* what `testdisk` found is an illusion, data that by chance(?) looks like a filesystem header or something. Maybe it's a dead end and you need to start over, take another approach (yet to be figured out). That's why I advised to make a backup. It seems there are fundamental problems with the original image. Do you know how exactly it was used/mounted when it worked?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, it was actually a disk file for Ubuntu operating system. But `testdisk` does not show any bootable partition... maybe this is a part of the problem.

Comment: Where did this `.vmdk` come from?  What type of filesystem are you trying to mount?

Comment: @jamesdlin I extracted it from remote virtual machine (vSphere). It used EXT4 by default(ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 0):

You can open .vmdk file with 7-Zip if you need to recover some data from inside of the virtual disk file. Then use copy option. 7-Zip does support partitions inside image files.

Comment: I tried unzipping with 7zip, but it stops at 49% with "unexpected end of data" error. Probably related to size information mismatch error.

Comment: @suhdonghwi in this case it is possible that the partition table in the vmdk file is not set to be till the end of vmdk file. You may need to recover proper partition table. Or the vmdk file is corrupted - too short.